# php file inside /var/www canot execute any shell scripting located outside /var/www

Tags: php, bash, web-applications, permissions, lamp

I have installed **LAMP** server, Ubuntu 12.04, php 5, apache 2. I want run some **shell scripts** (testproject.php) and **java files** located in **/home/home/Desktop/Project** folder from the php file inside /var/www i.e. in short when `**http://localhost/testproject.php**` will be refreshed the shell and java files should be executed.

this is the following line I used inside testproject.php :

```
$output = shell_exec('bash /home/home/Desktop/Project/print.sh');
echo $output
```

Initially when I changed permission of **print.sh** to 777, it worked fine, but in my project creates many auto generated files whose permissions cant be manually changed.

so I need some method to execute these java and shell scripts located in any possible directory.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: if your project is creating those files, then have the project set the permissions when the script files are created. That being said, as your exec call is written, the script file doesn't need to be executable, since you're telling bash to run it directly. e.g. `sh nonexecutable.sh` will run the script, but `./nonexecutable.sh` will not.

Comment: Have you tried chowning the files to apache?